# HTML & PHP & JS - Send POST after preview image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to post to a php page after it select an image from input button type=file and I do not know how do it.

I'm trying with jquery.redirect but it doesn't works. It's possible another solution for this?

Summary:

1) The user select an image from input button type = file. 
2) This image I want to post to another php page, to processing.
3) After this  I will show again this image in the initial page, after it processed.

The html code of the initial page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>WebCam UI</title>

      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="assets/css/custom-sugar-style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/jquery/jquery.redirect.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function HandleBrowseClick()
    {
      var fileinput = document.getElementById("browse");
      fileinput.click();

     }

    function previewFile() {
      var preview = document.querySelector('img');
      var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
      var reader  = new FileReader();

      reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        preview.src = reader.result;
      }, false);

      if (file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        $.redirect('tosquare.php', {'image1': file});       // Include script in function redirect
      }
    }

  </script>



    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                     <img id='imageCamera' class="img-sugar" src="assets/images/SUGAR.png"/><br><br><br>
          </div>

        </div>

      <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <form action="tosquare.php" method="post">
              <input type="file" id="browse" name="fileupload" onchange="previewFile()" style="display: none"/>
              <input type="button" value="Fes una foto" id="fakeBrowse" onclick="HandleBrowseClick();"/>
            </form>
          </div>

      </div>

</body>
```

In this line `$.redirect('tosquare.php', {'image1': file});     // Include script in function redirect` I want to post to tosquare.php with image1 parameter.

Could you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to upload the file using php?

Comment: I want to send to tosquare.php page

Comment: I want to send to tosquare.php, for what ???

Comment: I use tosquare.php to crop rectangle image and convert to square. After that it return the image to initial html page. May be there is another solution but I do not know.

Comment: You didn't explain how is it not working or what errors are you getting, anyway I would prefer using ajax to handle the croping

Comment: I get to post info using a input button but I don't get to post without this button. I need to post the data without click in the button.